# Query with datetime check excludes some records

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

For some reason my query does not take these records into consideration:

```
50  19/09/2019 15:00:00
60  19/09/2019 17:00:00
70  19/09/2019 18:00:00
```

What is causing that? Everything seems to work fine otherwise. It excludes the record which is beyond 7 days ago.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A:B, 
 "where B >= date     '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
    and B <= datetime '"&TEXT(NOW(),     "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")&"'", 0)
```

[image: 0]